# Navigation Bar and Status Bar colors/ invisible iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I'm trying to realize navigation bar and status bar that take colors of the image on top of controller. I've try with this two code:

```
self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

but it change only the main controller and I need to make invisible only the second controller not the main. Here is an image of what I want exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color of the image just put the image on top and later a visual effect view.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the navigation bar transparent with [this extension](https://gist.github.com/Infinity-James/cf4fbd319403a9ddfd92b966f91a6125) by calling:

`navigationController?.navigationBar.apply(.transparentWhite)`

in the `viewWillAppear` of any view controller in which you want this behaviour.

If you want other themes, define them as I defined the one in the gist:

```
static var transparentWhite: NavigationTheme { return NavigationTheme(attributes: [.font: UIFont(name: .avenirNextRegular, size:14.0)], barColor: .clear, tintColor: .white) }`
```